# What is the proper way to include highlightjs's CSS while using ember-remarkable?

Tags: ember.js, highlight.js

I have installed the ember-remarkable addon in Ember 2.7.  I am able to use the `md-text` component to format text content.  The content adds the appropriate `<code>` markup for fenced code blocks such as:

````
```javascript
    // An empty function
    function test() {
    }
```
````

However, the CSS to highlight that code as Javascript is not being included in my app.  I am currently styling my app in `app/styles/app.scss` using the ember-cli-sass addon.

One way to include the CSS would be to add a `<link>` to `app/index.html` to a CDN such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
```

Is that the best way?  Or is there an "Ember" way to easily include the styles that are in the `bower_components/highlightjs` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to include the Highlightjs CSS that I wanted is to add this line to `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
  app.import('bower_components/highlightjs/styles/default.css');
```

Of course, this is not limited to the default style.